# How to disable the debugger for specific files/namespaces

Tags: .net-core

I was curious if there is a feature to disable the debugger for a file or namespace, similar to how "Debug just my code" works. Last resort I can pull it out to a nuget package but I don't want to do that just for this.

Comment: What OS/IDE are you using?

Comment: Oops, using VS Code

Comment: Knowing the motivation mght help finding a solution